# Electron Node async call is not called

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, electron

I have some very primary test code in a function running under electron:

```
function test {
   log.info('this shows')
   let r = async() => { log.info ('will never show')}
   // or (async() => {log.info('will not show')})
}
```

why does the log line never show up in the log ? Its driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned `r` to a function but you never called it with `r()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the variable `r` is the function definition, you have to call the function like `r()` to trigger it.